# converting a dataframe to a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data frame like this:

```
         V1 V2        V3
    1    1  1 0.0000000
    2    2  1 1.6646331
    3    3  1 1.6649136
    4    4  1 1.7420642
    5    5  1 1.4441743
    6    6  1 0.7544465
    7    7  1 1.9796860
    8    8  1 1.0744425
    9    9  1 2.1503288
    10  10  1 1.0408388
    11  11  1 2.0822162
    ....
    841 29 29 0.0000000
```

I want to convert this data frame to a matrix. In this matrix `V2` should be the row and `V1` should be column

```
    [1]         [2]        [3]        [4] ....
[1]  0.0000000  1.6646331  1.664936    1.7420642...
```

How can I do that in r?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have contiguous values for your matrix (i.e. no gaps in the matrix) and the running order of values is continuous (i.e. row1;columns1:10,row2;columns1:10... etc), then....

Take the values in the appropriate column (`V3` in your case) and reshape them according to your paramters of matrix size...

```
m <- matrix( df$V3 , ncol = max(df$V1) , nrow = max(df$V2) , byrow = TRUE )
#[,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]      [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]    [,11]
#[1,]    0 1.664633 1.664914 1.742064 1.444174 0.7544465 1.979686 1.074442 2.150329 1.040839 2.082216
```

If you need to match the values (i.e. running order is not continuous) then you can take advantage of vectorised matrix subscripting like so....

```
#  Create empty matrix
m <- matrix( NA, ncol = max(df$V1) , nrow = max(df$V2) )   
#  Then fill with values at defined locations
m[ cbind( df$V2 , df$V1 ) ] <- df$V3
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do two things:

1. Reorder your columns
2. Transpose (using the `t` function)

So first create some example data

```
d = data.frame(V1=runif(5), V2= 5+runif(5), V3 = 10+runif(5))
```

then

```
t(d[, ncol(d):1])
```

or

```
t(d)[ncol(d):1, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job (where `df` is your data frame)

```
m <- do.call(cbind, df)
```